Oracle APEX - What is source of "Request" in "Request is contained in Value"
I'm looking at an APEX app where there is a "Close Dialog" process, with a Server-side Condition of "Request is contained in Value".  The Value input lists "CREATE,SAVE,CLEAR".  Where is that value set so that APEX can check that it's one of the items in that list?  The help text for that condition check only says "The page request is contained in the text you enter into the Value attribute."  So how is "page request" set?  Is it simply that I clicked a button located in the page layout "SAVE" region (for example)?  The oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/available-conditions.html#GUID-FC6694F1-24AA-4780-B8C1-650F5FBA4653) don't appear to elaborate.
Thank you

When a button is clicked and the behaviour of the button is set as "submit page" then the name of the button (not label, directly the name) is the request for page submit.
If the behaviour is "defined by dynamic action", then dynamic action of type "submit page" has the attribute of "request" so you can enter there.
Another option would be in the dynamic action of type "Execute Javascript code", apex.page.submit("request_name") is the function for submitting page with this request.

Thank you very much, Cengiz!  Super helpful.  I wish the docs elaborated on that.  Thank you!

REQUEST is covered in "Understanding URL Syntax", but yes, extra detail would help in the appendix you referenced https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/understanding-legacy-url-syntax.html#GUID-D5510BFC-AF94-4AAD-8B82-FF780A47601D

Glad it helped :)
